# Insert images in a table (rows = 1, columns = 2) docx python

Tags: python

I generated multiple graphs based on the data provided in a csv file and saved the name in a list. Now, I want to loop through the list and insert those images in a table (rows = 1, cols = 2) in a docx file. It works with 2 images but not with more than 2. I want to insert all the images in a table of 2 columns.

```
 for i, image in enumerate(['1.jpg','2.jpg']):
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    paragraph = row_cells[i].paragraphs[0]
    run = paragraph.add_run()
    run.add_picture(image, width=Inches(3), height=Inches(3))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRIi9.png)